# Animating googleVis plots

Tags: r, candlestick-chart, googlevis

I really like how motion charts look [here](http://lamages.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/accessing-and-plotting-world-bank-data.html) but I'd like to animate some of the other plots (rather than just the scatterplot chart).

For example, is it possible to animate a candlestick plot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In spite of your question, Ill answer as if you didn't care about using googleVis and just wanted to make candlestick charts with animation without regard to style. (mostly because I have terrible style, and because googleVis charts are made with non-R tools)

```
install.packages("quantmod")
install.packages("animation")
library(quantmod)
library(animation)

getSymbols("GS") 

chartSeries(GS) 


ani.options(interval = 0.05)
saveGIF({

    for(i in 1:20){  
    candleChart(GS,multi.col=TRUE,theme='white',yrange=c(0,1200));
      GS = GS+rnorm(3,50)  ; # replace this with something interesting.
}

}, movie.name = "animation.gif", img.name = "Rplot", convert = "convert", 
    cmd.fun = system, clean = TRUE)
```

[image: A moving candlestick chart]

Comment: Thanks Seth!  Not quite what I was looking for, but a pretty cool example!

Answer (score 2):

The `tkexamp` function in the TeachingDemos package helps with creating plots that can be controlled by various interactive controls.  One of the available controls is an animation control that can be used to animate your plot.  The `tkexamp` function works with pretty much any plot type that you can create in R, so you can create on screen animations of pretty much any R plot and either run the animation or manually control the passage through time.  The help page for `USCrimes` in the TeachingDemos package has an example of using this for an animated plot.

Note that this only works for interactive use.  To create an animation in a file to upload or give to someone else you can use the animation package as @Seth shows.